# Why do some students struggle so much with fractions?

Tags: primary-education, fractions

I read on multiple web pages something that implies that that some students really struggle with fractions but I could never find a detailed explanation of why. This question is different from [Are fractions hard because they are like algebra?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/7826/are-fractions-hard-because-they-are-like-algebra). I'm not sure whether this question is more suitable for Academia Stack Exchange or whether questions that would normally belong on Academia Stack Exchange but are about math belong here so I'm asking it here.

I also don't know in which way they struggle with fractions or what they mean exactly by it and probably cannot find the answer to that so that's why I'm not stating here in what way they struggle with fractions. I think there were researchers out there who researched how primary math education should be taught. If so, would it be possible for anyone to give me a lot of details about what those researchers discovered on the topic of teaching fractions to elementry school students and write them in a way that clearly explains in detail why some students are struggling so much with fractions and why certain methods of teaching are claimed to be the best way to teach given the current information researchers have about how students learn?

Comment: This does not tackle the issue of "struggling", but H. Wu wrote a text about pre-algebra (and other subjects) and how they should be taught; it might be of interest to you. See this link (p. 9) for the chapter on fractions: https://math.berkeley.edu/~wu/Pre-Algebra.pdf. Found the link to these notes on this question: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1857/books-about-elementary-mathematics-written-like-a-good-undergraduate-textbook?rq=1

Comment: Why wouldn't students struggle with fractions? You can multiply the top and bottom by 4 if you want, but you can't add 4 to the top and bottom or square the top and the bottom. You can cancel 4s if they appear on both the top and bottom, but not always. Sometimes your teacher tells you to "clear fractions" by multiplying by the denominator. Sometimes your teacher takes off points if you do that because multiplying by something changes the result. If you have two terms added together on top, you can split it into two fractions, but if you have two terms added together on the bottom, you can't.

Comment: Not listed in 'related' to the right, but on this topic, [How to explain fractions to 7 year old kid](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/14831/how-to-explain-fractions-to-7-year-old-kid)

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I think I also read the answers to that question and none of them answer this question.

Comment: Just a thought... Could it be because they haven't memorized the multiplication tables and have to rely on finger math or other "strategies" that can't be worked backwards to figure out lowest common denominators?

Comment: 1.  I think Chris is on the money, with the "why wouldn't it be hard".  In fact, the sort of surprise/curiosity that it is hard seems naive to me.  Brains are not computers, they have limited RAM.  I also think the question is closely related to a misconception that some simple fix (an explanation or the like) is all that is needed.  The brutal answer is fractions are hard.  Especially hard when you are new to them (many people here forget their initial struggles) and even harder when you are not above intelligence (as most here are).

Comment: 2.  The answer to making fractions click is probably just huge amounts of drill.  Yes, you can try different explanations, no waste.  If it helps, it helps.  But there is a misconception here that all that is needed is a more clear (or even worse, more rigorous) explanation.  That clarification is all that's needed.  Sorry, no.  This is like difficult tasks in sports or music.  You need lots and lots of exposure and practice.  Sure, an explanation may occasionally help, or some alternate method may work better with a particular kid.  But in general?  Volume.  Like QM, you get "used to it".

Comment: @guest I guess they find the existence of non whole numbers so unintuitive. If somebody who never managed to understand fractions asked a Stack Exchange question about how fractions are possible and it was obvious that their confusion was something like the lack of intuition for non whole numbers, somebody would probably write an answer addressing the confusion just like the answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839913/axiom-of-choice-where-does-my-argument-for-proving-the-axiom-of-choice-fail-he/1839929#1839929 addresses the author's confusion about why the axiom of choice is not

Comment: a theorem. Maybe that kind of explanation could then be tried out in school. If it's still confusing, somebody who still has the confusion by the time they're adult might ask another Stack Exchange question.

Comment: Another related post: [How to explain the flipping of division by a fraction?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/7837/511). See especially [the answer](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/7868/511) by @mweiss.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As for research on fractions education... there's a TON.

As for research on fractions education that rigorously measures cause and effect through randomized controlled experiments and long-term follow up... there is, I think, [little to nothing as of 2010](https://ies.ed.gov/ncee/wwc/PracticeGuide/15). And, since the field of education rarely uses that kind of research design, I doubt there is any need to update that report.

If someone out there is more familiar with the research on fractions pedagogy than I am, please know I would love to be contradicted on anything I've written. :)

Comment: I guess it's fine to write answers that you're not absolutely certain of because if researchers insisted on only using statements they can prove for certain are true, they would discover so much less and research would go so much slower, and that's why this answer is open to the possibility of contradiction.

Comment: In my experience, most education "research" is meaningless and does not discover anything. It is rarely scientific and is often designed to support the latest fad (often for political purposes). The latest maths fad, supported by "education research" in NZ cost millions in teacher retraining and students' maths scores dropped. Ministry of Education fired the university that did the testing and carried on. I wish education research would go a little more slowly, do proper scientific research, and discover how students really learn.

Comment: @Richard . Chief among the problems with ed research in the USA [dunno about NZ] is lack of funding. IIRC, typically, students' tuition money goes into the education faculty, then huge portions of it are transferred out. Ed faculties rarely get subsidies or big donations. So, there is just no money for big and long-term RCTs. Even if there was, measurement effects would still be hard to disentangle from treatment effects. So, ed research tends toward qualitative, intuitive, anecdotal, theoretical, short-term, small sample, etc. Kinda like medical "research" from the 1500's...

Comment: "So, there is just no money for big and long-term RCTs" Do you really need *money* to run a small scale school experiment? What you really need is just the unconditional control over the research subjects from teachers to students (and some brains to set the experiment up). The problem really is that one cannot get free hand with human subjects for ethical reasons, so instead of subjecting few people to experimental methods, we subject the whole population to various "teaching reforms" with often equally disastrous results, but then nobody can claim that he was more of a guinea pig than others

Answer (score 29):

There are many reasons why fractions are so hard for students to learn. Mostly, they're taught gibberish and assessed according to such gibberish.

---

**Example 1**

You are a 12-year-old student who has learned that "a fraction is part of a whole, such as part of pizza". So when you look at $\frac{2}{3}\times\frac{7}{5}$, you now must multiply pizza slices by pizza slices. This nonsense is obviously impossible to understand. Whether or not your teacher says to just memorize the procedures for multiplying fractions, that's how you're assessed so that's what you do. You give up on sense-making. You never learn what it means to multiply by a fraction, so, even years later, you still think that $\frac{2}{3}\times700$ must be bigger than 700 because there's 700 and multiplication. You're not sure if you need common denominators, though, because all those other fraction rules you tried to memorize are getting confused. "I hate fractions!" you say.

**Example 2**

Word problem: "A plane can go 600km/hour [fraction]. A retrofitted wing can cause it to go $\frac{1}{10}$ [another fraction] faster. How far can it go in half-an-hour [another fraction] with the new wing?"

Student: "I see the fractions. Where are the pizzas? My teacher says to draw a picture if I don't understand a word problem, so I should draw a pizza cut into 600 slices? How do I slice the pizza into plane travel?"

**Example 3**

Teachers tell you over and over again that whatever you do to the top of a fraction, you must also do to the bottom of a fraction. But they never tell you *why* or provide you with any sensory experiences or contexts to develop your intuition for this. They don't tell you *when* this is appropriate or useful or even what it means, and you're definitely never tested or graded on how it compares/contrasts with all the other things you can/should do with fractions. You seem to get check marks when you cancel zeroes in $\frac{600}{7100}=\frac{6}{71}$, though, so, when you're doing first-year calculus at university, you think you can cancel the $x$'s to simplify as follows:

- $\frac{x+3}{x+4}=\frac{3}{4}$
- $\frac{sin(x)}{x}=sin$

And you're pretty sure that $\frac{a}{b}\times2$ is the same thing as $\frac{a\times2}{b\times2}$, right? Whatever you do to the top, you also do it to the bottom... right? That's usually what got you good enough grades in the past...

**Example 4**

Sometimes teachers say that when given $\frac{26}{6}$, you should type $26\div6$ into the calculator. But I challenge you to find *any* textbook in North America that explains *why* this might be a reasonable thing to do and why the fraction bar and the $\div$ are *always* interchangeable while the fraction bar and, say, $\times$ are not. Even harder: find *any* textbook or test or teacher or tutor that asks students to compare and contrast $\frac{26}{6}$ vs $\frac{26\div6}{6\div6}$ vs $26\div6$ vs $\frac{26\div2}{6\div2}$ vs $\frac{26}{6}\div6$ vs $\frac{\frac{26}{6}}{6}$ vs $\frac{6}{\frac{26}{6}}$ vs $4.33333...$ vs $4\frac{1}{3}$ etc.

One reason that students are not taught or tested this way: they tend to bomb horrifically, immediately. If a student who types $26\div6$ into his calculator when he sees $\frac{26}{6}$ - only because he was told to yesterday - then a teacher can feel that student understanding is confirmed. The student gets a good report card, moves on to the next topic or grade-level, can apply to a prestigious educational program, etc.

The bad news - that the student is horribly confused by all the superficially similar expressions above - could have been uncovered immediately, but it almost never is. It's uncovered, say, when the student is in grade 12 trying to learn calculus and intelligent interpretations of all of those expressions is just assumed *even though it has never been tested*.

You may have been in comparable situations in the past; perhaps you're in some now. Are you actively trying to collect evidence that student understanding and retention are vastly weaker than they appear so that, if they are, grades will plummet immediately and cause hideous political fights for you, your students, your job, your admin, etc.? Or do you give into the pressure to give students sufficient grades to move them towards the next educational goal posts?

---

There are at least two ways main ways to avoid all this gobbledygook. The first is to **teach actual math instead of gobbledygook**. In the realm of fractions, that means teaching that **fractions are numbers** and in every single lesson and worksheet that involves fractions, to compare and contrast them with whole number(s), and to not introduce *anything* with two fractions until the student can do the same thing with one or two whole numbers and one fraction. Don't bother with $\frac{2}{6}-\frac{1}{6}$ until the student can draw a picture for $2-\frac{1}{6}$. Don't bother with common denominator fraction comparisons until the student can easily use number lines to compare $\frac{19}{4}$ and $4$ and $19$.

I affirm those who say to read the [work of Hung-Hsi Wu](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ewu/).

The second way to avoid this mental gobbledygook is meaningful interleaving.

If students are given a blocked (monotonous) set of exercises, such as:

> Find equivalent fractions for $\frac{1}{3}$, $\frac{5}{2}$, $\frac{10}{8}$, $\frac{6}{7}$, $\frac{2}{2}$, and $\frac{3}{8}$.

Then the normative response will be to mindlessly multiply the top and bottom number by, say, 3, over and over and never thinking about meaning. The students will just rush to finish with correct answers.

On the other hand, if students are given an interleaved set of exercises:

> Create a word problem and draw a picture for each of the following: $\frac{1}{3}\times2$, $\frac{1\times2}{3\times2}$, $\frac{1}{3}\div2$, $2\div\frac{1}{3}$, $\frac{1}{3}=1\div3$.

Then the students *must* think about meaning. They might need a caring teacher to gradually build them up to this kind of challenge, but there's really no comparison as to which set of exercises will make students think more meaningfully. In addition to being pedagogically difficult, though, this is also motivationally hard as students and parents - and most teachers - tend to care most about what's on the test, and these kinds of exercises are rarely on tests.

The short-run politics of determining the truth about student understanding is a nightmare. It lowers grades, so it prevents students from making honor roll or getting into an enriched math class or private school, it might make them lose a scholarship, it will cause tension in families, it will harm student status, parents scream "This isn't how I was taught math!", people will be convinced you're a bad teacher because student grades are low, students try to transfer out of your class, admin gets angry, etc.

I haven't figured out how to deal with such politics yet. :P

Comment: *Create a word problem and draw a picture for each of the following:* This sounds like a great exercise, and if you are teaching kids of this age and assigning stuff like this and giving kids feedback on it, then you're a hero and I hope my grandkids can be in your class someday. But I suspect that very few K-6 teachers are willing to read this amount of written work and write detailed feedback on it, especially given that in the US they may have classes with 35 or 40 kids. There is also the issue of teachers' own mathematical competence, which is not addressed in this answer. I suspect [...]

Comment: [...] that quite a large fraction of K-6 teachers do not themselves understand fractions and division well enough to do this exercise.

Comment: I'm not complaining about your answer but I did upvote it but didn't put a check mark beside it because your answer doesn't give a more detailed description of why some students struggle so much with fractions that you explained clearly.

Comment: @BenCrowell . I tend to work 1-on-1 with students so I do assign problem sets like the one I recommended. I've never tried it in a classroom setting, but I'm pretty sure one way to build up to that is "assessment as learning". Sadly, this would require teachers to create tons of material by hand, because you won't find tough stuff like that online! "Assessment as learning" exercises, if graduated properly, would help teachers master fractions as well. This is mostly conjecture, though, until I try it in a classroom in a few weeks... :)

Comment: @Timothy . To answer your question more directly, then, the psuedo-math in Examples 1-4 represent what many students experience in school. In contrast, what I wrote about fractions being numbers that must mentally integrated with whole number knowledge - that is something many students never experience deeply. Even if *exposed* to the critical notion that a fraction is a number, it is rarely emphasized and even more rarely graded, so students do not expend the mental effort to internalize it.

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything Don't worry about your answer not being good enough. The fact that I didn't put a check mark beside it doesn't mean you did something wrong not making it a better answer. It just means I'm trying to help the Stack Exchange community research which types of answers tend to solve people'e problems by not indicating that that it solved my problem. It's totally fine with me that you gave more detail in a comment instead of editing your answer. I just don't want to put a check mark beside the answer when the answer itself is in its current form. If you happen to decide on your

Comment: own that despite that, you still care about making your answer better, feel free to edit your answer. Editing it just by adding in what you added in the comment probably still wouldn't make me feel like it was good enough to put a check mark beside it. Without realizing it, I might be making it so that no way of writing the answer will make it worthy of a check mark.

Comment: Can you (or anyone else) suggest a place to start in reading the many, many things on this page: https://math.berkeley.edu/~wu/ ?

Comment: @ChrisCunningham . Which aspect of math education did you want to learn about?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything I was hoping to head down the paths of "teach actual math instead of gobbledygook" and "In the realm of fractions, that means teaching that fractions are numbers" ...

Comment: @ChrisCunningham There is a link clearly identified as "Teaching fractions in elementary school: A manual for teachers".

Comment: @RustyCore I don't appreciate your comment; there are about a dozen links on that page that have to do with fractions. The person who wrote this answer was probably thinking of a specific one of those as a jumping off point. If not, fine. The one you picked out is probably a reasonable place to start.

Comment: I've only stumbled upon this thread today. Such a great answer!! I especially love Example 3! But then, this part seems to contradict your claim that fractions are just numbers -- unless I'm misunderstanding something. (And I admit that I haven't read Wu's book, although I plan to now.) Probably that's one of the reasons why fractions are difficult -- because it's a multi-faceted concept. I'd say that introducing fractions as numbers at first makes sense. But then the concept must be extended into understanding fractions as ratios. After all, $\frac{x+3}{x+4}$ isn't a number, is it?

Comment: @zipirovich - Thanks! I'm not sure which part of Example 3 contradicts the notion of fractions as numbers. In the big picture, students need to learn roughly in this order: (1) Fractions are numbers, (2) Equivalent Fractions, (3) Fractions as Quotients [quotients are just particular type of number], (4) Fractions and quotients as ratios, rates, and probabilities. And, yes, $\frac{x+3}{x+4}$ can be all of those things.

Comment: I like H. Wu but I think his (and others') complaints about multiplying pizza slices are misguided. Of course it makes sense to model fractions with pizzas, at least as much as modeling them with points on a number line. Those points are represented by a clump of ink molecules, so to multiply fractions we have to multiply a clump by a clump? I don't know about you, but I multiply numbers, not clumps. Obviously nobody can learn fractions this way! Not exactly a fair criticism, of course, but neither is it when we switch clumps with pizza slices.

Comment: One of the best answers I've read on this site so far!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know for sure.  But I think a part of the problem comes from notation.  I don't know how you've approached math education, but I find that students are often times confused by the distinction and overlap between the concept of division and the concept of fractions. I think the cause of this confusion is found in the notation we use and the order in which we teach the subject.

We cant tell them that 10/2 = 5 is division and it requires that the top number be bigger than the bottom number... and explain to them that this is an *operation* between two integers....

... and then show them something like 2/7 and tell them this isn't an operation between integers, even though it looks like it, but an entire numeric entity all by itself.

My suggestion has always been to restrict ourselves to the use of the obelus when talking about division, and leave the slash or horizontal bar for topics on fractions.

Then after you explain division of fractions, you start showing them the relationship between division of integers and the entity known as a fraction. At this point the fraction bar and the obelus becomes the same object.

It's my hope to convert the traditional "believe this in faith that they are the same thing because I said so" into a genuine epiphany that they can have themselves.

Comment: I'm not a teacher. I read on the internet that a of of students struggle with fractions. I can't observe their performance and learn that way. That's why I asked the question. I guess students feel like they have the ability to think. I guess they don't want to assume that a fraction is equal to division until they see that for themselves. I guess they have no concept of taking as an axiom that a division is equal to a fraction so they get confused. I guess it doesn't occur to them to be like "The teacher said it so it must have been proven to be true." I had trouble concentrating in school.

Comment: When my mother told me that a fraction was the same as a division, I think I understood it. I believe I was like "I guess it can be shown to be true without assuming it."

Comment: I'm not sure why I put a check mark beside the first answer. I don't really feel like removing it now. I guess I was convinced that I had access to the answer if I could bother to read the whole thing. Maybe I was satisfied with knowing there was research on it. This answer is worth an upvote. I guess the confusion about being told fractions are the same as a division between the same numbers is a useful thing to know. However, I'm still not fully satisfied. Would removing that confusion fix the problem or would they still be confused about something. I guess the fraction symbol is used

Comment: because it's so obvious that $\frac{2}{6} + \frac{3}{6} = (\frac{1}{6} \times 2) + (\frac{1}{6} \times 3) = \frac{1}{6} \times 5 = \frac{5}{6}$ but it's not obvious that $\frac{5}{6} = 5 \div 6$. Maybe their brain doesn't make the connections of how to derive that because it's such a long problem to locate and find such a connection in the first place. If you happen to feel that you can in good conscience try different strategies until you find one that works really well, I would love it if you update this answer after trying it. However, if you write an answer in 20 years and I'm not a Stack

Comment: Exchange user anymore by then, I might not see it. I have an idea. First of all, when you try to teach them so many things, they don't explore the things that really matter in depth with their brain. So pick out less to start teaching in depth. When teaching how to add fractions, you could ask how to add $\frac{3}{4}$ and $\frac{5}{6}$. Then show that it can be reexpressed as $\frac{9}{12} + \frac{10}{12} = 1\frac{7}{12}$. However, when you present the instructions as shown at https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/13150/how-to-teach-sum-of-fractions-to-students, it confuses them.

Comment: $\frac{6}{7} \times 5 = \frac{6}{7} + \frac{6}{7} + \frac{6}{7} + \frac{6}{7} + \frac{6}{7} = 4\frac{2}{7}$. Maybe for this, using improper fractions will work better so you would write $\frac{30}{7}$. Then let them get the idea of how to multiply any fraction by a positive integer. Next for something like $\frac{6}{7} \times \frac{2}{3}$, you could explain how once you get the answer to $\frac{6}{7} \times \frac{1}{3}$, you can get the answer to $\frac{6}{7} \times \frac{2}{3}$. Next explain how $\frac{6}{7} \times \frac{1}{3}$ is the number such that when you right multiply it by 3, you get

Comment: $\frac{6}{7}$. Next, give it as a homework problem to determine what $\frac{6}{7} \times \frac{1}{3}$ is. Maybe the teacher will remind them of the definition of it but leave it for the student to teach themself how to find it. I picked a bad example. It's more challenging if the first number doesn't have a numerator that is a multiple of 3. I think it's going to get them practicing the skill of teaching themselves things which is better than telling them how to do it. Once they're mastered multiplication of fractions, then they should be left to teach themselves how to divide fractions. Once

Comment: you know what multiplication is, it's straight forward to know what division is. After they got a lot of practice with it, then it may be worth giving $5 \div 6$ as an example. Then they'll see that it in fact is $\frac{5}{6}$. Then they won't be confused about the fraction notation in the quotient rule. I realize that formally, you can't have a fractional notation whose numerator and denominator are not both integers. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number. However, I also got their point that the fractional notation can be taken to be synonymous with division.

Comment: "Its my hope to convert the traditional 'believe this in faith ...' into a genuine epiphany that they can have themselves." Teach this the same you would any other primary math content: sensory experiences, simple story, and prior knowledge connections. "If you have 8 pieces of licorice and share it with 4 kids, how much licorice does each kid get? What if you have 3 pieces of licorice and 5 kids?" Have them draw it and write equations. Here: I'll get you started.  :)  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Os4uT1S0mFrsNIolXGg15uHuJ1nllHSOUOZWyEDol_k/edit

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly, a fraction has twice as many components as (say) an integer, and these components greatly increase the numbers of ways they might interact, in a combinatorial fashion. Consider an arbitrary binary operation on integers: $a \odot b$. With only two components to the arguments, there is only a single relation that needs consideration: the one between $a$ and $b$. On the other hand, consider fractions:

$$\frac a b \odot \frac c d$$

In this case, there are actually $6$ relations that might need consideration: $(a, b), (a, c), (a, d), (b, c), (b, d), (c, d)$. Sextupling the cognitive load on the student is quite a leap forward. Of course, the relations that need consideration/manipulation are different for the various different operations of addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, etc., so there's a lot to digest and memorize there. (This is to say nothing of mixed numbers, with 6 components, for a total of 15 possible relations.)

Consider the operation of addition on proper fractions: In most school situations this involves (1) factoring the denominators $b$ and $d$, (2) composing the least common denominator by inspecting those factors, (3) multiplying each component $a, b, c, d$ appropriately to create the desired denominator in each fraction, (4) adding the modified numerators and writing over the common denominator, (5) factoring the new numerator again, and (6) possibly canceling like factors in the numerator and denominator (and then multiplying the remaining ones back together to simplify).

So in summary: It seems by my estimation that the conceptual and mechanical work in handling fractions is about $6$ times that of integers. Granted that [some theories of working memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_memory#Capacity) suggest a capacity of perhaps 4 or 7 chunks (and less in small children), this may in fact be at or beyond the limit of many children's short-term memory to manage.

Comment: I can't quite figure out what you're saying. To a young and inexperienced person, it would appear that you're assuming they are able to take the rules on how to perform calculations on fractions as a given, and they just have trouble holding all those rules in their mind. I think the way they learn them best is to introduce them to them using a student centered approach. Give them an intuition on why non whole numbers exist. For example, start with teaching them only how to add fractions with the same denominator and how to right multiply one by a whole number. I don't think you're quite right

Comment: about the reason.

Comment: @Timothy: Regardless of how it's taught, introduced, or intuited... at the end of the day, yes, students need to hold all those rules in their mind. Many people can't, and the various rules for different operations cross-contaminate each other.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins The LCM of $b$ and $d$ is not needed beforehand for adding rational numbers $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$. One can simply multiply the numerator and denominator of the first fraction by $d$ and the numerator and denominator of the second fraction by $b$, and add the two numerators together to get $\frac{a \cdot d + b \cdot c}{b \cdot d}$.

Comment: @MadeleineBirchfield: Not really relevant, because any school situation or book I've seen expects the answer to be simplified, which your proposed result isn't. E.g., see the process as given in [OpenStax Prealgebra Sec. 4.5](https://openstax.org/books/prealgebra-2e/pages/4-5-add-and-subtract-fractions-with-different-denominators), which is standard, and finding LCDs a highlighted first step.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins that's why the last step (6) is still required, i.e. find the GCD of $a \cdot d + b \cdot c$ and $b \cdot d$, and divide the numerator and denominator by the GCD to get a simplified fraction. See i.e. the process as given in Wu's textbook [Pre-Algebra Sec. 1.3 and 3.1](https://math.berkeley.edu/~wu/Pre-Algebra.pdf)

Comment: @MadeleineBirchfield: To my knowledge, the work of Wu (with whom I've corresponded) doesn't actually get used in schools. Your proposal requires students working with larger numbers in the intermediary step, which is why it's opposite the advice in any widely used textbook of which I'm aware.

Comment: Anyway: My answer is in the context of actual curriculum students face (as noted, "In most school situations..."), not some hypothetical alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is actually very complicated. I myself never really understood fractions till I learned of it's construction through natural numbers. The idea of fractions as a formal expression of describing fraction quantites (lack of better word) is pretty easy to understand for most people , for instance, half a pizza, that's easy, right? But the issue is figuring out the correct general rule to add fractions and why that should be the rule i.e: why is:

$$ \frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d} := \frac{ad + bc}{bd } ?$$

One way of understanding it is through the idea presented in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/677913/688539) but again this is adding more sub concepts to understand this main.

I think at a Young age, people find it difficult to do things which require understanding connections between different fields at once/ identifying what are the right connections to see between two different things so they can understand each of the thing individually.

Comment: Re: your last paragraph: how about just cultivating confidence? By sufficiently exposing learners to the process of intellectual discovery, being methodical, and reasoning that involves more than one step. Technical topics naturally seem formidable when applying attention span to them continues to feel alien.

Comment: In my personal experience, it was just continually failing to understand till I understood the pre-requisites for the rigorous definition... maybe it was just due to my teachers being bad tho but seeing many Youtube explainers makes me think other wise @ryang

Comment: I was riffing generally that, especially when it comes to technical topics, waving the white flag at the first opportunity is a vicious cycle. Like reflexively dismissing alien cultures and never getting to broaden horizons. Sorry for rambling!

Answer (score -3):

Some students struggle with fractions because some teachers taught them fractions in a way they can not see the relation between fractions and daily life.
In [this](https://youtu.be/JKu26uLe2zM?t=100) Spanish-language video, a lady explains fractions. She draws a pizza sectioned into six equal pieces, one piece is then selected and eight "unit" (dots) placed on it. She then asks, "what was the whole number whose sixth part equals eight?" This explanations also works for proportions.
Additionally Ratios and rates are explained in a [different video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQ2nYUBVvqI)
. I add a third [video](https://archive.org/details/NasaConnect-Trror-RationalNumbers-StudentActivity) about fractions, which was made by NASA.

Comment: I downvoted this answer. The question was why some students struggle with fractions, not how fractions work.

Comment: I also downvoted this answer; it doesn't answer the question. If there was a question "What is the best youtube video to explain fractions," this would be a reasonable answer.

Comment: actually this question put all stress on students